# Target only single product page

Tags: posts, woocommerce-offtopic, post-type

At first sorry for my bad English!
I try to hide  #mceu_27-body and #wp-content-editor-tools on products page (editing mode) like on the pics for certains authors!
This work find :

```
    add_action('admin_head', 'wwc_my_custom_css');
if (!current_user_can('edit_pages') ) {
function wwc_my_custom_css() {
     echo '<style>
               #mceu_27-body, #wp-content-editor-tools{
                  display:none !important;
               }
          </style>';}
}
```

But it affect all posts type and I just want it on products post type so I tried that but it doesn't work :

```
add_action('admin_head', 'wwc_my_custom_css');

if (!current_user_can('edit_pages') && is_product() ) 
function wwc_my_custom_css() {
     echo '<style>
               #mceu_27-body, #wp-content-editor-tools{
                  display:none !important;
               }
          </style>';}
}
```

[image]
Thx

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean to use this on a single product's page, right?  If so, try this:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'wwc_my_custom_css');

function wwc_my_custom_css() {
if (!current_user_can('edit_pages'){
   global $post;
   $isProduct = $post->post_type == 'product'; // use the actual name for product

   if ($isProduct ) {
     echo '<style>
               #mceu_27-body, #wp-content-editor-tools{
                  display:none !important;
               }
          </style>';
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried and it doesn't work! But I finally found a other solution that match my wishes! I totaly remove the long description for certains users with the following code : 
 function remove_product_editor() {
    if (!current_user_can('edit_pages')) {
  remove_post_type_support( 'product', 'editor' );
}}
add_action( 'init', 'remove_product_editor' );